# Facebook Share Button on Main Page in Wordpress

Tags: facebook, wordpress, button

I have this as my facebook share button on my "single.php" template in Wordpress:

```
<script>
function fbs_click() {
u=location.href;
t=document.title;
window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u='+encodeURIComponent(u)+'&t='+encodeURIComponent(t),'sharer','toolbar=0,status=0,width=626,height=436');return false;
}
</script>
<style> html .fb_share_link { padding:0px;background:url(http://www.mydomain.com/images/compartir-fb.png) no-repeat top left; }</style><a href="#" onclick="return fbs_click()" target="_blank" class="fb_share_link"></a>
```

I tried adding the same code to my "index.php" but it doesn't seem to work, when i click on the button, it instead shares my main website "www.mydomain.com" but I want it to share each individual article. So itried replacing:

"u=location.href;" to "`u=<?php the_permalink() ?>`"

but all it does it opens a new tab with www.mydomain.com

I am really trying to figure out where to place `<?php the_permalink() ?>`?

Answer (score 0):

> So itried replacing:

```
"u=location.href;" to "u=<?php the_permalink() ?>"
```

That should only give an error in your browser’s JavaScript console, since it is not valid JS syntax, because you neglected to put a text literal in string delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

try to convert it as below ...

```
wp_reset_query();
if(is_home()){
$url = site_url();
}else{
$url = get_permalink();
}

<script>
function fbs_click() {
u='<?php echo $url;?>';
t=document.title;
window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u='+encodeURIComponent(u)+'&t='+encodeURIComponent(t),'sharer','toolbar=0,status=0,width=626,height=436');return false;
}
</script>
```